# why ping lost when interface add to ovs bridge

Tags: bridge, ping

I have two linux, there are server1 and client1.
server1 has several interfaces and two of them added to ovs bridge - ovsbr0 ( eth2, eth3).
client1 has inteface in the same L2  as server1.

i  have IP 
10.10.1.56 - assigned server1 ovsbr0
10.10.1.4  - assigned client1

when I perform ping from client to server,  about 70 percent package is lost.

```
   64 bytes from 10.10.1.56: icmp_seq=161 ttl=64 time=0.360 ms
   64 bytes from 10.10.1.56: icmp_seq=162 ttl=64 time=0.372 ms
   64 bytes from 10.10.1.56: icmp_seq=172 ttl=64 time=0.722 ms
   64 bytes from 10.10.1.56: icmp_seq=186 ttl=64 time=0.710 ms
   213 packets transmitted, 67 received, 68% packet loss, time 212013ms
```

tcpdump -i ovsbr0

```
07:27:30.184172 IP 10.10.1.4 > 10.10.1.56: ICMP echo request, id 26834, seq 2, length 64
07:27:30.184203 IP 10.10.1.56 > 10.10.1.4: ICMP echo reply, id 26834, seq 2, length 64
07:27:32.192084 IP 10.10.1.4 > 10.10.1.56: ICMP echo request, id 26834, seq 4, length 64
07:27:32.192102 IP 10.10.1.56 > 10.10.1.4: ICMP echo reply, id 26834, seq 4, length 64
```

show that no one frame is lost

tcpdump -i eth3

```
07:32:10.162735 ARP, Reply 10.10.1.4 is-at fa:16:3e:f4:23:2c (oui Unknown), length 28
07:32:11.162111 IP 10.10.1.4 > 10.10.1.56: ICMP echo request, id 29535, seq 7, length 64
07:32:12.162000 IP 10.10.1.4 > 10.10.1.56: ICMP echo request, id 29535, seq 8, length 64
07:32:13.162079 IP 10.10.1.4 > 10.10.1.56: ICMP echo request, id 29535, seq 9, length 64
07:32:13.719576 LLDP, length 71: openflow:1
```

show that frame is lost

why frame lost while it goes from eth3 to ovsbr0   on the server ?

ovs-vsctl show

```
...
   Bridge "ovsbr0"
        Port "eth3"
            Interface "eth3"
        Port "eth2"
            Interface "eth2"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

there is root cause of controller which manage this OVS bridge.
If controller is deleted then traffic goes correctly. If controller is configured traffic is lost.